# how to get secondary storage uri or root directory of secondary storage of all devices in android

Tags: android

the secondary storage access is the main problem in android for all device but why?if anyone can solve this then it will be very helpful to me.who can know about access of secondary storage means external sd card of any device in marshmallow.please check below code link and help me.Its big problem still don't get solution.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sojccopr46gbqgg/CheckExternalSDCardDemo.tar.gz?dl=1

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether External Storage is Available or Not using below code:

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

If it returns true use below code to get access to External Storage:

```
 getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()
```

For more information visit: [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: I used it in external storage but i wanna talk  about secondary storage.Please check it.secondary storage  means removable sd card

Answer (score 0):

before you access the external storage or root storage you need to define user permission in manifest and as well as in java file of your code where you want to access it before this ask the run time permission for external storage
  for adding run time permission go threw https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html 
or any run time tutorial